# use stdout of a process as a command in bash

Tags: bash

I have a rust script that prints something with a newline character at the end. I would like that line to be launched in bash instead of only being printed out. It acts as:

```
echo "my_line"
```

while I just want

```
my_line
```

as I would type it regularly in a terminal.

How would one achieve this and would it also be possible for a backgrounded process without a terminal open?

Comment: do you mean you want to execute a command in Bash from Rust, or you want to use Bash to execute the output of a Rust program?

Comment: I tried both approaches on my own and I couldn't figure it out. I would like whichever is easier to implement and efficient.

Comment: The *easiest* way is to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to tell the shell to execute your string as if it were input, although this has more limitations than starting a subprocess does. Assuming your Rust executable is named `foo`, does running `$(./foo)` in Bash solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
$(echo "my_line")
```

to execute the command after command substitution.
Check https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html.

Answer (score 1):

You should use command substitution if possible, but there are times when you need things to be interpreted by the shell instead, like conditionals, redirects, or shell variables (`cmd1 && cmd2`, `cmd > file`, `$var`). If that is the case, then you should create a subprocess in Rust. This will spawn Bash, then tell it to run whatever is in `command_string`. Note that the command string parameter is a single string, and should not be split into vectored args:

```rust
use std::process::Command;
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let command_string = "sleep 3 && echo done";

    let out = Command::new("bash")
        .args(["-c", command_string])
        .output()
        .expect("failed to run command")
        .stdout;
    println!("{}", String::from_utf8(out).unwrap());
}
```